# How would I unpause a node in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have some nodes that I would like to run their action in the start menu. How would I do this? I have these clouds that move from left to right and I want to un pause them. I tried a lot of different things but cant seem to get it to work. Thanks here is the code but its not working for me. Im in spritekit swift.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        view.scene?.paused = true
  }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    //movement of clouds

    cloud.paused = false
    cloud2.paused = false
    cloud3.paused = false

}
```

}

Comment: Don't put your .paused methods inside the update method. they will get called every frame which isn't needed.

Comment: How should I go about doing this? I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. I tried making the cloud.paused = false in a function and the didmovetoview and still doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.speed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKAction/speed) property of your SKAction to pause and resume the action:

```
//Stops your action
yourAction.speed = 0

//Resumes your action
yourAction.speed = 1
```

Also don't put code in the `update` method which doesn't need to be called every frame. Put it inside a `didMoveToView` method or something similar.

Comment: I have a question. I have view.scene?.paused = true in the didMoveToView is that okay, because I need some of the methods to be paused. Also I tried the .speed and its not working. Thanks.

Comment: okay it works, but I want to ask you one more question. I have this function thats in a block and when i do the speed = 0 it still runs. Why does that happen?